# Spring boot Authorization with external role server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, role-manager

I am trying to implement a role management for in spring boot APIs. 
I went through the [link](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-oauth2-role-based-authorization) but I could not get the below details

```
1. Here they are using @Secured, I am not sure when actually role verification is called
```

Because there is a separate server which has the Role and Authorities details, Hence I want to call External Server to fetch the role and verify the Authorities ? here external server will give role details like userid and roles and allowed action like Delete, Create etc .

```
2. how the username or userid is fetched while validating the access ?
```

Comment: 1. When the method with the @Secured annotation is called.

2. What type of "External server" do you have?

Comment: here external server will give role details like userid and roles and allowed action like Delete, Create etc .

Comment: Yes but what it is I need to know? A Database, an Active Directory, SAML Provider or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is data base.. I am using ldap for Authentication now need to add role management.. all the roles details are stored in data base. I can not access that db directly I have to access through mirco service call. Many of my micro services needs the role management

Comment: In that case you have to implement the UserDetailService to fetch the data.

Comment: Is there any spring code example if I want to use LDAP only for both Authentication and Authorization .. ?